# Choosing best branching model for common framework based different applications development

Tags: branching-and-merging

I was reading many articles about version control systems like SVN, Git and various branching models (feature based, release based and others) but none of them did not seem to fit our project requirements.

We (team) are going to develop a framework, which will be used as core for different applications. So, there will be one framework and more than one different applications built on that framework. Each application will have usual project cycle: builds, releases... Framework itself won't be released but may have tagged different versions. During the development of application, we want to commit some common features to the framework (if we see that feature is great and future applications should have it).

So each application is like a separate branch of framework, but it will never be fully merged back (because it's a separate application) and there is need do some commits to framework (trunk). Some online articles such commits (without merging whole branch to trunk) gives as negative examples, so we are confused.

What version control system and branching model do you recommend for such development cycle?

Answer (score 1):

> So each application is like a separate branch of framework, but it
>   will never be fully merged back (because it's a separate application)
>   and there is need do some commits to framework (trunk). Some online
>   articles such commits (without merging whole branch to trunk) gives as
>   negative examples, so we are confused.

This part scares me a bit. If you are going to have a framework, then you need to take care of it like any other lump of code, and you don't want multiple versions running around for any reason except maintenance of existing releases or work on future releases. So each of your "application" projects can have a branch where they modify the framework as required for the application, but I recommend the framework trunk be updated often so that it evolves in a way that best serves the needs of all of your applications. In general, when  branching for code going forward, you want to sync up with the master and put code back into the master as quickly as possible to avoid lots of work handling merges and also give others the benefit of the work.

You should put your framework in a separate area (or repository if you are using a DVCS like git or hg) so that it's distinct and may have its own release cycle if necessary.

The DVCSs are all the rage these days, git and hg being the most popular, so you should look into them. They have different ways of handling branching. Their power lies in the fact that there is no centralized repository so it's more flexible and reliable for larger teams.